# A French character says "What's news?" - is it idiomatic English or a mistake?

Tags: grammar

In Ken Follett's TV series "World without end" the French Queen says, "What's news!" Is this conversational question correct or is it French put into English?

Comment: I would need more context to be able to answer this.

Comment: At least the Wall Street Journal uses this expression http://www.wsj.com/news/whats-news  - But you can also say What's the news/ What's your news?

Comment: In the book, there is no mention of "what's news".. There is however two instances of "What news" (by Caris and Merthin respectively). Is that what you mean? More context would definitely help... Which episode is it?

Comment: The Queen is a quintessential _quidnunc_.

Comment: For context: I found a transcript of the show [here](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=world-without-end&episode=s01e04) that has an example of the phrase "what's news".

Answer (score 1):

*No, it is not conversationally correct.* English-speakers do not go around asking each other "What's news?" or exclaiming "What's news!"

Conversationally, we say "What's new?" We can also say "What's up?" and "What's going on?"

We can also ask "What's the latest news?" or, for short, "What's the latest?" Or "Have you heard the latest (news)?

We do not say "What news?" We might say: "What news do you have for me?" But we would not say it as a greeting.

I have no idea why the French Queen says, "What's news!" in the show you mention.

Comment: 'What news?' is also an uncommon and informal but accepted phrase to ask after recent news.

Answer (score 0):

"What's news?" sounds odd. Either of the following would make more sense: "What's new?" (what's up, what's happened lately?) or "What news?" (what news is there or what news do you have?)

Answer (score 0):

In the context you describe, "What's news!" makes no sense. I suggest (without having seen the scene) that you misheard her, and it was actually "What news?", a fairly common contraction of "What is the news?"; that is, she is asking what news is available.

About the only context I can fit your sentence into would be something like a Journalism 101 class, in which the professor starts by asking "What's news? Can anybody tell me? You, in the third row. What is news?"